# google-chrome <filepath> shows error. Access Google Chrome from Terminal

Tags: google-chrome, terminal

I am trying to open a file in google-chrome from my terminal. Whenever I run command google-chrome  on Terminal, it says:

**zsh: command not found: google-chrome**

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG9Nj.png)

How should I go about it?

Comment: I have already installed Google Chrome in my PC.